# Can I use an extended active record association in a has_many :through declaration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've extended many of my has_many declarations to filter / join / preload associations.  I'd like to re-use some of these extensions when I declare has_many :through relationships.  Is this possible?   Should I take a different approach?

Example:

I have this in my Library Model:

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meals, :dependent => :destroy do
    def enabled
      where(:enabled => true)
    end
  end
end
```

My Meal Model has this:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :servings, :inverse_of => :meal, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I'd like my library to have many servings, but only from the enabled meals.  There are a couple ways I can do this:

```
# repeat the condition in the has_many :servings declaration
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :servings, :through => :meals, :conditions => ["meals.enabled = ?", true]
end

# declare a different meals association for only the enabled meals
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enabled_meals, :class_name => "Meals", :conditions => [:enabled => true]
  has_many :servings, :through => :enabled_meals
end
```

**Is there any way to re-use the extension to my existing :meals declaration?** (def enabled in the first code block)

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like you want to use activerecord-association-extensions, as described here http://blog.zerosum.org/2007/2/8/activerecord-association-extensions.html.

I haven't tried it, but I think you could do:

```
  module LibraryMealExtensions
  def enabled?
    where(:enabled=>true)
  end

  def standard_includes
    includes(:servings)
  end
end

class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meals, :dependent => :destroy, :extend=>LibraryMealExtensions
  has_many :servings, :through => :meals, :extend=>LibraryMealExtensions
end
```

Not sure about the "enabled=>true" there - you might have to say

```
where("meals.enabled=true")
```

b/c of confusion with aliases.